# Can I use a virtual method defined in a template class inside another method?

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

- I have a template class that has two methods one virtual and one normal.
- The normal one calls the virtual one.
- The implementation of the template class overrides the virtual method always.
- The problem seems to be that when creating a class from the template one... calling get_data()... crashes the program.
- I have to feeling that even though I override the method it stills holds 'nullptr' what I'm I doing wrong?

```cpp
virtual M *get_map() const { return nullptr; };

int get_data() const {
    return (*get_map())[_data_owner].data;
}
```

Comment: This is impossible to determine without a [mcve]. You need to visit stackoverflow.com's [help], learn [ask] questions correctly, then [edit] your question so that it meets all requirements of a [mcve] that anyone else can use to run to reproduce your problem. Without more information, the only possible answer to "Can I use a virtual method defined in a template class inside another method?" would be "Yes, of course".

Comment: Could you add the code for the parent and the child? Just the relevant methods will do.

Comment: Are you calling the virtual method during construction of base class? Until base class construction is done, virtual function calls go to the base class, ignoring the subclass

Answer (score 0):

I seems like I needed to add an "override" keyword when overriding the method.
Even though I read it was not needed, in my case I needed to add it to make it work. Everything works nicely, sorry for the not so documented post